# Alter default copy/paste mechanism in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have issue, when working in reach text editor, when I do copy of link automatically href become lower case.

I want to intercept data, between copy alter them and paste them.

I found something on w3c, but I don't know how to paste data into document.

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  var oldData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  var newData = '<b>Ha Ha!</b> ' + oldData;

  pasteClipboardData(newData);

  // This is necessary to prevent the default paste action.
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

What I should do on this line ===>  `pasteClipboardData(newData);`

How I can paste my new data into clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try below function:-

```
export function copyTextAreaToClipBoard(message: string) {
  message = message.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, String.fromCharCode(10));
  const cleanText = message.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
  const x = document.createElement('TEXTAREA') as HTMLTextAreaElement;
  x.value = cleanText;
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(x);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do it with `document.execCommand('copy');` method cause it is obsolete.
I want to do it on way which I gave above.


But thanks for trying.

Comment: @PredragDavidovic You can use `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)` but seriously `document.execCommand('copy');` is commonly used in most websites although it is marked as obsolete. It can be still used in the future.